# Displaying UI widgets in Cardview in android L

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-cardview

I am trying to create an application in cardview, the cardview contains two textviews which needs to be placed next to each other, but the textviews are getting overlapped. Is there any mechanism to place elements like its done in RelativeLayout(layout_below or layout_toRightOf) for Cardviews.
I am able to do this by adding shadows to the Relativelayout and making it look like Cardview, I want to do this in the Cardview.

My Layout code is below :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Textview one"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="36sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Textview two"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="36sp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Currently it is displayed like the picture attached:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the description of [CardView](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/ui-widgets.html#cardview)

> CardView **extends the FrameLayout** class and lets you show information
>   inside cards that have a consistent look on any app. CardView widgets
>   can have shadows and rounded corners.

As you probably know, in `FrameLayout` there are no constraints or relations between views positioning. They will be displayed one above each other. If you want to use different hierarchy inside a `CardView` please just use any layout you want inside. For example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Textview one"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="36sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Textview two"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="36sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Treat the `CardView` only as an outer decoration and you can use ANY layout inside. So if `LinearLayout` is not appropriate you can use `RelativeLayout` etc.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I am able to do so by having the contents of the cardview embedded in a layout. I was looking for options not to do so as they are expensive.

Comment: You wrote: " I am able to do this by adding shadows to the Relativelayout and making it look like Cardview" - it basically means that you are able to "mimic" the `CardView` using a `RelativeLayout` and adding a shadow to it, not that you know you can add `RelativeLayout` inside of it:)
But OK. So you have two solutions: 1. Use inner layout as I suggested in my answer or 2. Extend the `CardView` and implement your custom measure and layout methods on your own (the same way as you would create a custom layout and position children from code). There is no other way to do it.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot extend CardView.

Comment: Why would you not be able to do that?